# JqueryMobile - menu panel not slide when closing

Tags: jquery-mobile, menu, slide

I have a problem with the panel.
When I open the menu, panel nice slide right but when I click to close panel it just disappears, not slides to left as it opens.
Do you know what's the problem?

This is my link for menu:

```
<a href="#leftpanel1" data-role="button" data-icon="list" class="icon-list menu_button" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog"></a>
```

And menu:

```
<div data-display="overlay" data-role="panel" id="leftpanel1" data-position="left">
        <ul data-role="listview">
         <li>...</li>
        </ul>
```

I'm using jquery-1.11.0.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.4.1.js .
Here is jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SpWgy/50/

Comment: Are you closing the panel by clicking outside it, or with code?

Comment: Clicking outside or on link <a href="#" data-rel="close"></a>

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle, or do you only see it in specific devices? Also, what version of jQM and jQuery are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using jquery-1.11.0.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.4.1.js .
Here is jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SpWgy/50/

Comment: looks like it is a jQM 1.4.1 issue. Updating your fiddle to 1.4.2 eliminates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/SpWgy/54/